# How should I remove credentials that was stored in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I think I made a mistake when I cloned my repository. There is a prompt message to input a username and password but maybe forgot a letter or number in username and password so it came back with an error. How should I undo it and clone again to have the username and password prompt again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows:-

- Go to Credential Manager.
- Go to Windows Credentials.
- Delete the entries under Generic Credentials
- Try connecting again. This time, it should prompt you for the correct username and
  password.
  [image]

[image]

Comment: with a little bit of guessing I can find your credentials, MASK them COMPLETELY